# Requests proxy across multiple scripts in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a question about proxies. Say my main code is like this

```
import testing
import requests
def get_tor_session():
    session = requests.session()
    session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                       'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
    return session
requests = get_tor_session()
print testing.getsite("http://icanhazip.com").content
```

and the script it uses, testing, is like this

```
import requests
def getsite(somesite):
    return requests.get(somesite)
```

it doesn't seem to use the proxy across the main script. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

OP here nevermind
If anyone is wondering

```
testing.requests = requests
```

does it